# Angular 2+ add ng-bootstrap Modal to component library

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-bootstrap, angular-library

I'm working with ng-bootstrap and I would like to add a reuseable modal to the component library I've built.

***I have my template***

```
<p>
<ng-template #messageModal let-closeModal="close('Cross click')">
    <div id="resultModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="mt-3">{{header}}
            </h4>
            <button id="messageModalClose" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           {{message}}
        </div>
    </div>

</ng-template>

</p>
```

***and Component***

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 @Component({
  selector: 'ms-modal',
  templateUrl: './ms-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ms-modal.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MsModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() message:string;

  private _modalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    size: 'lg',
    centered: true
  };


  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  OpenModal(_messageModal) {
    this.modalService.open(_messageModal, this._modalOptions);
  }

}
```

*I've added @Inputs for the header and message
My component library builds fine*

***In my application that I import my component library into I've added the 
modal tag***

```
<ms-modal *ngIf="showModal==true" [header]="header" [message]="message"> 
</ms-modal>
```

When I set showModal=true nothing happens.

```
showModal:any = false;

this.showModal = "true";
```

I guess I'm not sure how to get this wired up correctly to use my modal from my component library in my various applications.

Comment: Can you show where you set `showModal`? Also, the top of the template has a `<p>` tag. Is it closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have got this working and I had several things wrong.

Please remember that I am working in a Component Library not just the application.

Inside my Component Library...

***I have my template***

```
 <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="mt-3">
        {{header}}
     </h4>
     <button id="messageModalClose" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
         (click)="closeModal()">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      {{message}}
  </div>
```

***and Component***

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalOptions, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng- 
bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ms-modal',
  templateUrl: './ms-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ms-modal.component.scss'],
  //encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MsModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() message:string;

  private _modalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    size: 'lg',
    centered: true
  };


  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  closeModal() {
    this.activeModal.close();
  }
}
```

***I import my component into my app module***
    import {msModalModule } from 'ms-components';

***I add 'msModalModule' to the @NgModule imports array and also add the component 
referenced by the module to entryComponents***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     HttpClientModule,
     FormsModule,
     msModalModule    
  ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
entryComponents:[MsModalComponent]
```

})
export class AppModule {}

***Now in my app.component.ts I add a function to handle opening the Modal and pass in the input values***

```
OpenModal(header,message){

***NgbModalOptions is optional
const modalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false,
  size: 'lg',
  centered: true,
};


 const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MsModalComponent,modalOptions)
 modalRef.componentInstance.header = header;
 modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your showModal to true using a boolean value, like:

```
this.showModal = true;
```

instead of setting it with a string value, like you were doing:

```
this.showModal = "true";
```

because your `*ngIf="showModal==true"` is using the boolean value `true` instead of the string value `"true"` to conditionally show your modal.